# Start-up Situation

Tags: boot, partitioning

Recently replaced Windows 8 with Ubuntu.

At start-up I receive the following

```
Unlocking the disk/dev/disk/by-uuid/b7bc470f-59f7-47d1-b2a7-230cc562c3(sda5_crypt)
Enter paraphrase
```

What does it mean?  I have 2 other computers utilizing Ubuntu and have never encountered this.

Answer (score 1):

Your sda5 (root) partition was encrypted.You have to give the passphrase to unlock it, so that it would bootup.

This is because you selected encryption option at the time of installing Ubuntu.Give the same passpharse as you given while encrypting the disk.

[image]